# Images(PNG,JPG) won't show on Heroku App after deploying Node JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, image, heroku

So I have built my app using Node JS. Everything worked out perfectly via testing locally using localhost:3000.

When I was testing app locally, I've used path such as

```
<p>
    <img src="http://localhost:3000/images/logo/sample.jpg" />
</p>
```

to make my browser get image file and render it.

Of course I've set it up **/public** as my static folder inside **app.js**

So I've realized after deploying to Heroku that using **http://localhost:3000/images/logo/sample.jpg** gets me **404 error** code but I've resolved by removing **localhost:3000** and just used **/images/logo/sample.jpg**

Using Chrome's Developer tool against my Heroku app (after deploying), I was able to see that images were loaded perfectly but ended up not displaying. And one strange part that I've noticed was the type of document. Both **.png** and **.jpg** files inside Heroku was read as **html/text** type rather than image type.

Is there a method which I can tell Heroku that my **.png** or **.jpg** files aren't **html/text** type?

I do not want to use S3 or paid cloud services... Just want to use Heroku's free plan.

Thank you all.

Comment: While in developer tools, can you open the link to the image and it displays correctly?

Comment: you can try to run this command `heroku local` on your local machine to test your app, you can see if it works on you local.

Comment: I've tried heroku local and tested on my local machine. Strangely, some images are loaded and other images are broke. Heroku local can identify some image as png or jpg type and within some pages, heroku local detects image as html/text type rather than png or jpg...

Answer (score 1):

If you happen to have developed your application using windows, the image extension case is not insensitive, however when you deploy your application to Heroku, Heroku is Linux based hence cares about the case you are using. For example you may have an image **background.JPG** but in your application you use **background.jpg**, unfortunately it will not work on heroku deployment.

Comment: This is exactly what happens in heroku.